# Replacing specific value in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array

Newbie! I'm generating a chess board through a 2D array and trying to replace the array value specified by "white queen" and "black queen" coordinates, right now just working on getting the white queen to work.

Below I want to replace 0 by a 1 where whiteQueen[0, 5] is, but the loop replaces the whole column by a 1 instead of just the j specified. I'm wondering where I'm going wrong and if there's a potentially easier way to go about this that doesn't involve looping.

My code:

```
function generatedBoard (whiteQueen, blackQueen) {
  
let mainArr = new Array(8).fill([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
  
  for (i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < mainArr[i].length; j++) {
      if (i === whiteQueen[0] && j === whiteQueen[1]) {
        mainArr[i].splice(j, 1, "1")
      }    
    }
  }
  return mainArr
}

let whiteQueen = [0, 5];
let blackQueen = [5, 0];

console.log(generatedBoard(whiteQueen, blackQueen));

Result: 

[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `mainArr` array is created using the `fill` method, `new Array(8).fill([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`, in the new created array all the elements (`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`) are refrenced to the same value in the memory.

So when you try to update one value in an array because all arrays are linked hence the value is changed in all of them.

To make an array that is not linked like this you can make it sort of manually using a loop, like this:

```js
const mainArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  const row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) row.push(0);
  mainArr.push(row);
}
```

---

For updating, you can do it much more easily like this:

```js
mainArr[whiteQueen[0]][whiteQueen[1]] = 1;
mainArr[blackQueen[0]][blackQueen[1]] = 1;
```

The above code will replace the exact value with `1`.

---

**Final Code:**

```js
function generatedBoard(whiteQueen, blackQueen) {
  const mainArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) row.push(0);
    mainArr.push(row);
  }

  mainArr[whiteQueen[0]][whiteQueen[1]] = 1;
  mainArr[blackQueen[0]][blackQueen[1]] = 1;

  return mainArr;
}

let whiteQueen = [0, 5];
let blackQueen = [5, 0];

console.log(generatedBoard(whiteQueen, blackQueen));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is creating an array, with each element referencing the same array i.e. `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

```js
let mainArr = new Array(8).fill([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Changing any element of `mainArr` will change all it's elements.

When are using [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method, you have to use a static value.